# Sencha Touch 2.3 app causes iPhone 5 to freeze or crash

Tags: sencha-touch-2, iphone-5

I have created a Sencha Touch 2.3 app and tried to build it on iPhone5 using xcode. Sometimes when I deploy it, the phone freezes and then the only choice left is to force a reboot.

This happens occasionally only while trying to build it.

Has anyone else come across this ?

At first, I assumed it happens once in a while only while trying to build and deploy it.

But recently, someone reported a similar issue with another sencha app on an iPhone5 which was already downloaded and used several times. While launching this app, the screen went white and after a while the phone rebooted !

Is Sencha Touch apps causing this ?

Comment: Please check the logs relevant to your app and post them here. Have you tried with actual phone or simulator? If it is in simulator, you can check the logs with from MacOS. If it is in actual device (iPhone5 in this case), you can get the logs from the iTunes and there are apps available in apple store. Please revert back.

Comment: It is deployed on actual device. I have TestFlight integrated and TF did not show any crash reports.

Comment: So, I hope it is not problem with xcode / iPhone5s. Maybe, it is problem with your sencha touch2.3 code. Could you please try to use try catch in your codes (suspicious code) and alert exception in catch block. try{/*your code*/}catch(e){alert(e);}. Since testflight sdk wont give logs for sencha touch. It gives logs for xcode. If you use cordova, you can call testflight sdk logs. Let me know.